# How to convert list of scala Xml elements to single scala Elements?

Tags: xml, scala, scala-xml

So I have

```
val list:List[Any];
def toElement(a:Any):scala.xml.Elem;
```

And I want to write somthing like

```
val result = <span> {list.map(toElement).toElem} <span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea...

```
val list:List[Any] = List(1, 2, "test", 3.5)

def toElement(a:Any):scala.xml.Elem = {
  scala.xml.Elem(null, a.toString, scala.xml.Null, scala.xml.TopScope)
}

val result = <span> { list map toElement } </span>
```

results in

`<span> <1></1><2></2><test></test><3.5></3.5> </span>`

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, I think what you're after may be something like this:

```
// List of different types
val list: List[Any] = List("one", 2, "three", 4:Long)

// Conversion function for type 'Any' - (note .toElem or .toXml isn't a
// member of 'Any' - so that's why we need to create this)
def toElement(a: Any): scala.xml.Elem = <hello>{ a.toString }</hello>

// Usage example
val result = <span>{ list.map( toElement(_) ) }</span>
```

But I guess it really depends on what type of objects you're expecting in the list, and what sort of XML elements you want them to end up looking like.